# ASP - Disable a button to prevent user from clicking twice

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on an ASP website. I want to disable a button after the user clicks the button.

If the users click the button twice by mistake, the DetailsPage.ASP is executed twice and duplicate entries are inserted into Database.

How to disable a button in ASP code to prevent the users from clicking twice?

```
Page1: Mainpage.asp page
     <form action="DetailsPage.asp" method="POST">
     <input type="Submit" name="Submitbutton" value="Update Details">
```

How to prevent the users from clicking the button twice or alert them if they try to click second time?

Another other suggestions to handle this type of scenario will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Ashok

Comment: The most robust way to prevent duplicate entries is probably at database level. I recommend you add an "SQL" tag to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% dim disabled
If request.form("Submitbutton") <> "" Then
disabled = " disabled"
End If %>
```

Then code your button like this

```
<input type="Submit" name="Submitbutton" value="Update Details" <%=disabled%>>
```

Comment: This requires a round-trip to the server, by which point your impatient user has clicked the button dozens of times. :/

Answer (score 3):

Add a handler for the form in JavaScript;

```
function submitForm(form)
{
    form["Submitbutton"].disabled = true;
    return true;
}
```

Attach it:

```
<form action="DetailsPage.asp" method="POST" onsubmit="submitForm(this);">
```